# Counting integers $n \leq x$ that are representable as sum of $2$ squares

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, summation, prime-numbers, algorithms

I want to count exactly how many integers $n\leq x$ can be represented as the sum of $2$ squares. Call this count $C(n)$. For example, there are $330$ integers not exceeding $1000$ that are the sum of $2$ squares, so $C(1000) = 330$.

I am aware of the asymptotic approximation to this count, and of the condition that an integer must fulfill in order to be representable as the sum of $2$ squares. [This OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A102548) gives the partial sums I am interested in, but no particularly useful formula. Is there any efficient way to count these integers other than checking each one?

Comment: While it's not guaranteed, for a reasonably clear sequence like this if there isn't a formula on OIES then I would suspect there isn't a known one at all.

Comment: I don't believe there's any more efficient method. For small numbers you could use something like similar to the Eratosthenes-Legendre Sieve, excluding only multiples of the $4k-1$ primes, but adding back multiples of $(4k-1)^2$, etc. I'm not sure if that's actually mor efficient though.